# Special kind of DB relation

Tags: java, hibernate

I've got 3 tables : *A* (id, type, b_id), *B1*(id, message) and *B2*(id, message). *A* table record should be binded with *B1* or *B2* table, that depends on type field. If type is 1, bind with *B1*, else - *B2*. How can I do that using hibernate? I was trying to do something like follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps.A")
public class A{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int index;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private int type;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B1 b1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B2 b2;
```

I could check type in get method if type equals 1 or 2 and return null or object. But console says:

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: A column: b_id(should be mapped
>   with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: [Inheritance using discriminator-value](http://tech.lalitbhatt.net/2014/07/mapping-inheritance-in-hibernate.html)

Answer (score 1):

Change the annotation  to @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)

UPDATE: To clarify. I would change the entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ps.A")
public class A{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int index;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private int type;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private B1 b1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private B2 b2;

    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private Integer bId;
```

Thus you can use the pure Integer bId (plus type) for creating. After saving the b1 and b2 should be filled.

Comment: But that thing should be insertable and updatable.

Comment: You can create B1 or B2 instance and set A there.

Comment: Could we chat or something?